# What are some programming patterns to perform atomic operations involving two systems in node.js?

Tags: node.js, algorithm, atomic

Our application's API handler (written in Node.js) updates AWS Dynamo DB and Redis cache.
We want to ensure the update operations on Dynamo DB and Redis Cache are atomic (both succeeds or both fails).

Is it possible to do this in plain node.js or using some library?

We tried a very basic design using Promises:

```
let promise1 = dynamoDB.update()
let promise2 = redisClient.set()
let result = await Promises.all([promise1, promise2])
```

- if both promise1 and promise2 successful, return task is success
- if promise1 success, and promise 2 fail:
  Rollback dynamodb update
  return task is fail
- if promise1 fail and promise2 success:
  Rollback redis cache update
  return task is fail
- if promise1 fail and promise2 fail:
  return task is fail

But in practise such solution cannot be implemented as neither AWS DynamoDB nor Redis cache supports rollbacks.

So we are looking for solutions that's practical to implement.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reliable way to do exactly what you want.  You need to design your systems so that every atomic change in *either* Redis or DDB transitions your system into a new consistent state.

Typically something like this is practical:

1. In Redis, set a PENDING state that says "At *timestamp*, a change in DDB is being attempted.  You need to check there to see if it succeeded"
2. Update DDB
3. Update Redis with the final state.

When a reader checks Redis and sees the PENDING state, it needs to check DDB to get the real result.  If the reader determines that the operation that was pending did not succeed, and it's been too long since *timestamp*, then the reader should revert Redis back to its original state.

Note that you must take special care to ensure that multiple writers interact consistently when they try to update at the same time.  That would be done by using compare-and-set operations in Redis, ensuring that one writer's PENDING state is never overwritten by another client until it's been long enough since  to prove that the original writer has failed.

Comment: This solution is practical to implement. Let's translate this approach into node.js code. Thanks for answering!